# EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync Exception The parameter is incorrect 'User'

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-mobile

My UWP apps suddenly throw the following exception on Win 10 Mobile Build 10.0.14342.1001. They still work fine in the emulators.
Is anybody experiencing the same problem? Is there a workaround?

*Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
WinRT information: user
Additional information: The parameter is incorrect.
user*

To ensure the problem is not related to something specific with the apps email messages I sent the following simple message which causes the same problem.

```
Dim em As New Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage
em.To.Add(New EmailRecipient("a@b.c"))
em.Subject = "test"
Await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(em)
```

[Link to test case.](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=661C679EE037F677!290981&authkey=!ADjKRfnGUy1FsF0&ithint=file%2C7z)

Comment: without any line of code were you pass a parameter 'user' we can't help. Debug the app inside VS on target 'device' and look what fails.

Comment: Updated my question with a code sample. I don't pass a parameter 'user'. I don't see a property 'user' in the API. The apps crash at ShowComposeNewEmailAsync with the exception stated.

Comment: I have the same issue, where the same code used to work before on earlier builds (haven't changed this for months).

Comment: submit it in the feedback hub app. My phone doesn't support RS builds, so I can't test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the insider build. No workaround known.

MS was informed about it via feedback and the [MS forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9885dc12-fd56-41ed-8669-c630e62c4551/uwpemailmanagershowcomposenewemailasync-exception-the-parameter-is-incorrect-user?forum=wpdevelop).

Got fixed with Windows 10 Mobile Insider Preview Build 14356.

Answer (score 1):

Build 14342 is an insider <del>'fast'</del> build, meaning it is not production-ready and you are likely to hit errors from time to time. Please file feedback using the Feedback Hub, and wait for the next build. Thanks for being an Insider!

Comment: @peter-torr-msft I understand your point about being an insider and such. However, this build was also released to the slow ring (which is still insider, I understand). A lot of users are affected :-(

Comment: Like Geert I am concerned because many users are running this Win10 insider release. I did immediately report the problem via Feedback and did yesterday post to the MS forum too. My apps use email to allow reporting problems with trace files attached. This is also the only way for myself to get at my traces files.

Comment: Thanks for filing feedback. I'll make sure the team sees it, although I can't say when it will be fixed.